# PHP loop through JSON array and get key value pair

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a PHP function in which I am trying to loop through a JSON array. 
The JSON array is passed to the PHP function via a GET request from android studio volley. The URL looks like this... (whereArray is the jsonArray passed as a parameter to my PHP script).

`https://xxxxxxx.co.za/api/select_from_fact_sighting.php?whereArray=[{"country_name":"Botswana"},{"region":"Southern Africa"}]`

The PHP function looks like below.
First I json_decode the passed parameter and I can see that there are 2 rows in $jsonArray because $elementCount = 2.

But my problem comes when trying to loop through the jsonArray and access the Key of each row and the Value of each row. In the code below the $where array is always empty. Can someone indicate what I am doing wrong in the foreach loop? Essentially I need to get the Key value pairs from the jsonArray array.

Thanks

```
    public function select_from_fact_sighting($whereArray) {


        $jsonArray = json_decode($whereArray, true);
        $elementCount  = count($jsonArray);        

        $where = array();

        foreach($jsonArray->entries as $row) {
            foreach($row as $key => $val) {
                $where[] = $key . " = " . $val;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is that `->entries` coming from? Just iterate on `$jsonArray` and it should be fine.

Comment: `print_r($jsonArray)` <- show us the output of this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$jsonArray->entries` is not a valid array value from the code you posted, just change it to:

```
public function select_from_fact_sighting($whereArray) {

    ...
    $jsonArray = json_decode($whereArray, true);
    $elementCount  = count($jsonArray);        

    $where = array();

    foreach($jsonArray as $row) {
        foreach($row as $key => $val) {
            $where[] = $key . " = " . $val;
        }
    }
    ....
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks very much the quick response